# Installing Pyramid without Chameleon

Tags: python, installation, pyramid, pip

Pyramid has both Mako and Chameleon as install dependencies.  My intention is to exclusively use Mako templates and, considering that I have a little obsession for removing unused dependencies, I uninstalled Chameleon.  To avoid errors from `distribute` I had to manually edit the `requires.txt` file in the Pyramid installation.

So far, I haven't found any errors, although I haven't been beyond basic examples.
Is there a way to choose only one template engine at installation time?  I could be mangling the installation manually but I will have a dozen virtualenvs to maintain.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If pyramid does not require both and they are truly optional requirements for optional features it may be possible for them to use [extras](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) which is designed for that.

`pip` supports [this](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#the-requirements-file-format) so could give you your desired at install time behaviour.

To correctly implement this would require working with pyramid upstream to change there setup.py to use `extras_require`. However if it is just a case of choose one this may not be suitable, but you may want to raise it in their issue tracker/bug system.